# Django is not returning success to html template

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I have created a contact form and when the processing is done, it is returning data in the error div tag instead of success div tag.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Contact

def contact(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    subject = request.POST['subject']
    message = request.POST['message']
    
    contact = Contact(name=name, email=email, subject=subject, message=message)

    contact.save()

    # Send email
    send_mail(
       "From e-learning:"+subject,
       message,
       'senderemail@gmail.com',
       ['receiver1@gmail.com', 'receiver2@gmail.com'],
       fail_silently=False
     )

    send_mail(
       "Welcome to e-learning",
       "Thank very much for contacting us.We received your enquiry. Our team will contact you as early as possible.",
       'senderemail@gmail.com',
       [email, 'receiver1@gmail.com'],
       fail_silently=False
     )
    
    messages.success(request, 'Your request has been submitted, a realtor will get back to you soon')
    #return redirect('/listings/'+listing_id)
    #return redirect('/')
    return HttpResponse("Details are submitted")
```

The template, I have pointed to.

```
<form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="POST" role="form" class="php-email-form mt-4">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="id_contact_name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="id_contact_email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="id_content" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>
```

Bootstrap [template](http://%20https://bootstrapmade.com/bethany-free-onepage-bootstrap-theme/) (free version) I used.

All the output, whether error or success, it is coming to div with class error-message only instead of sent-message.

Comment: Hello, can you please attach the template fragment, where actual message is being displayed?

Comment: The template fragment is already provided. The second code part.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is being submitted from Ajax
The free theme you have taken will have a folder named Forms delete it and change your code like this

```
def contact(request):
if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
    contact = Contact()
    contact.name = request.POST.get('name')
    contact.email = request.POST.get('email')
    contact.subject = request.POST.get('subject')
    contact.message = request.POST.get('message')
    contact.save()
    #send email here
return JsonResponse({'massage':"massage"},safe=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit, but now it is showing empty message completely. With error div tag showing

Comment: If the error is not showing properly, then checking in the console will be there.

Comment: No, there is no use on applying your code, that's what I meant to say. Earlier it showed in error section every output.Now, it is showing nothing

Comment: I have also gone through this problem and I have also started the form.

Comment: i will share you a demo code with screen shot